# Global variable not accessible using this keyword within specific code snippet in typescript

Tags: typescript, variables

I have defined a variable globally in typescript, within one function I am not able to get that variable using `this` keyword

This is my code

```
imageTemplate.adapter.add("latitude", function(latitude, target) {
  const ctx = target.dataItem.dataContext as any;
  let polygon = this.polygonSeries.getPolygonById(ctx.id);
  if(polygon){
    return polygon.visualLatitude;
   }
   return latitude;
})
```

Getting error at `this.polygonSeries.getPolygonById(ctx.id);`. `Property polygonSeries does not exist`.

This is how I have declared `polygonSeries` variable

```
public polygonSeries:any;
```

How can I solve this issue?

In the below answer in comment box, I came across lots of theory which I don't want. I am looking for solution.

Comment: The solution is to use arrow function `(latitude, target) => { ... }` instead of normal `function` declaration. But you should try to understand the theory, to see _why_ this is a solution.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am able to access. You can write your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by replacing `function` definition with arrow function definition `=>` as below

```
imageTemplate.adapter.add("latitude", (latitude, target) => {
  const ctx = target.dataItem.dataContext as any;
  let polygon = this.polygonSeries.getPolygonById(ctx.id);
  if(polygon){
    return polygon.visualLatitude;
  }
  return latitude;
})
```